# Using a public JSON API and displaying it as html

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've been through quite a few different threads here on using external JSON files but all of them seem to display nothing when I run the script.

I'm trying to display the first [this](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/) JSON url.

raw data:

```
{
    "total_market_cap_usd": 178408752351.0, 
    "total_24h_volume_usd": 6196679281.0, 
    "bitcoin_percentage_of_market_cap": 57.24, 
    "active_currencies": 883, 
    "active_assets": 344, 
    "active_markets": 6243
}
```

not quite sure how to go about it. I saw a tutorial that suggested this using PHP:

```
<?
$url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/'; 
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$price = json_decode($data); 
echo $price[1];
```

but this seemed to return nothing also.

Comment: is `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your php.ini ?

Comment: @mim. yep just checked it. was already enabled

Comment: can you add a dump of `$data` ?

Comment: @mim sorry. not quite sure what you mean by that

Comment: What does `var_dump($data)` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please Look at the API instructions

```
$url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/'; 
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$price = json_decode($data,true); 

//var_dump($price);
echo $price["total_market_cap_usd"];
```

Comment: ok  I was wondering why nothing was working. Don't laugh, but I wasn't running it through my localhost. I don't know why i decided to right click the file and view it in my browser.... your method worked. thanking you kindly

Comment: by the way. would you know of a way to seperate it to make it look a little more neat? eg: $160,500,700 rather than 160500700

Comment: e.x   $num = number_format(160500700);
 echo "$".$num;

Comment: I'm not laughing at you. I just want you to have a problem. You can first look at the API instructions, and that's the right way

Comment: Thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a JSON content as visible HTML, you have to format it using HTML tags.

You can also use the [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag to make the browser maintain format.

But first you have to render the JSON object as a String. For doing that in JavaScript, simply use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

For example:

```js
var json = {
  "total_market_cap_usd": 178408752351.0,
  "total_24h_volume_usd": 6196679281.0,
  "bitcoin_percentage_of_market_cap": 57.24,
  "active_currencies": 883,
  "active_assets": 344,
  "active_markets": 6243
};

var asString = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);

var asHtml = asString.replace(/\n/gi, '<br />');

console.log(asHtml);

document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML = asHtml;

document.getElementById('placeholder2').innerHTML = asString;
```

```html
<span id="placeholder"></span>
<hr />
<pre id="placeholder2"></pre>
```

Comment: does this method just get the set data? I need to display up to date data from the URL